# Recommendation for Laptop for College?

Tags: laptop

I am majoring in ee in college. There are specific laptop requirements given, which are:

- A 64 bit version of Windows (recommended), Linux, or Mac OS.
- A 64 bit dual core processor from AMD or Intel (i7 Intel or AMD Phenom II recommended)
- 4 Gigabytes of RAM with capacity to upgrade (8 gigs recommended)
- 12 inch or larger screen with resolution of 1366x768 or higher
- NVidia (recommended), AMD (recommended), or Intel integrated graphics processor
- USB 2.0 ports (3.0 recommended)
- Built-in or add-on 100 Mbit wired Ethernet (integrated 1,000 Mbit wired ethernet recommended)
- Hard disk with 256 Gigabyte capacity (512 recommended)
- Touch screen recommended

They recommended any model of: Lenovo ThinkPad, Lenovo Yoga, Dell Latitude, Dell Precision, HP EliteBook, etc.

Could anyone help me find a laptop that isn't too expensive (<~$1500) that satisfies these requirements or could recommend a favorite model out of this list?

Thank you so much! This is really needed, any reply would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Any thickness or weight requirements?

Comment: None are listed!

Comment: gigabit's standard. Anything with fast ethernet is probably truly terrible

Comment: Any idea as to what software you're likely to be using? Also, weight requirements should probably be based on your preferences (I know I'd rather not lug around a laptop heavier than 2 kg all day)

Comment: I don't know about the software, but it shouldn't be too heavy because I would need to carry it around.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would recommend Dell's New [Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/inspiron-15-7567-laptop/pd?ref=PD_OC), more specifically, the [1,149.99 model](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/inspiron-15-7567-laptop/pd?oc=cai157w10p7s510&model_id=inspiron-15-7567-laptop). Yes, it is a gaming laptop, but it provides good performance at a relatively low cost.

### Reasons for my recommendation:

**Fits all Your Provided Requirements**

- Comes with a 64bit OS (Windows 10 Pro)
- CPU supports 64bit OSes: i7 7700HQ (4core/8thread)
- 16GB DDR4 RAM, upgradable to 32GB
- 15" Display - 1080p
- nVIDIAGTX 1050ti GPU w./ 4gb of vRAM
- 3x USB 3.0 ports
- Gigabit ethernet
- 2x Internal Harddisks: 1x 256GB SSD & 1x 1TB HDD

---

N.B.

- It does not have a touch-screen, but you did not specify it as being absolutely necessary.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too hard, considering that these requirements are fairly basic... As long as you don't go with a mac (they're overpriced), you should be fine. I would recommend a Lenovo Ideapad Y700 $1000 - $1600 15" model, as they're quite good and not too overpriced, and satisfy the specs quite easily, though you won't get an SSD until the $1600 model, but that also has 1TB of HDD storage as well as the 512GB PCI-E-based SSD, 16GB RAM as opposed to 8GB, and an extra 2GB of Video RAM for the GPU, which is a GTX 960M.

To find these, go to Lenovo.com and navigate to Products > Laptops > Ideapad > [Y700 Series](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/y700-series/?menu-id=y700_series).

With the 960M, you can also get some fairly decent performance if you're a gamer, though you won't be able to run games on ultra settings at stable frame-rates, it'll be all you'll really need for a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ASUS N56JR](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N56JR/).

- 64 Bit Windows or 64 Bit Linux (Ubuntu tested)
- i5 or i7 CPU (seems to depend on the region which one is shipped, the one I tested has a i5, the one tested [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAAoZSgGNQk) has a i7)
- 8 Gigabytes of RAM
- Full-HD screen
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760M and Intel HD Graphics 4600
- USB 3.0 ports (2 on the left, 2 on the right)
- Built-in Gigabit wired Ethernet 1 TB HDD (can be replaced by a SSD)

Only downside to your requirements: It has no touch screen

[image: ASUS N56JR]

Answer (score -1):

I use a Lenovo Yoga 700 for my school work. While I do not have the higher model it can have an i7 fitted. The laptop comes with 8gb of ram and has a touch screen. 
In my experiance it is a very useful laptop, difficult to game on, it does not possess a fan. While this is down to the fact it is rather small and light, yet also the size of an A4 sheet.